# Slick Lightbox not loading images fetched after an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, slick.js

I am currently using the slick-lightbox plugin https://github.com/jongacnik/slick-lightbox. I am trying to load content into it dynamically after an AJAX call.But the carousel does not get updated .

```js
$('.slider-lightbox').on('click', function (e) {    
    var pageKey = 2;
    var itemId = '562A4B65A09A4215927346F8ECF67759';
    var url = '/api/threesixtyviewapi/GetAllCommunityGalleryAjax';
    $.post(url, { page: pageKey, itemId: itemId }, function (data, status) {
        var pageNumber = data.page;
        var newsItems = data.items;
        if (data.length > 0) {
            var imgGalleryBlock = '';
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var imageUrl = data[i].ImageUrl;
                var videoUrl = data[i].VideoUrl;
                var thumbnail = data[i].VideoThumbnailUrl;
                var isVideo = data[i].Is360View;
                var pendingCount = data[i].pendingCount;
                if (isVideo == true) {
                    imgGalleryBlock += '<li class="video active"><a href=';
                    imgGalleryBlock += videoUrl;
                    imgGalleryBlock += ' width="400px" target="_blank"><img src=';
                    imgGalleryBlock += thumbnail;
                    imgGalleryBlock += ' alt=""/><img class="play-btn" src="/images/video-icon.svg"></a></li>';
                }
                else {
                    imgGalleryBlock += '<li class="image active"><a href=';
                    imgGalleryBlock += imageUrl;
                    imgGalleryBlock += ' width="400px" target="_blank"><img src=';
                    imgGalleryBlock += imageUrl;
                    imgGalleryBlock += ' alt=""/></a></li>';
                }
            }
            $('ul.slider-lightbox').append(imgGalleryBlock);
            window.onload = timedRefresh(000);
            pageKey++;
            $('.img-gallery-main-btn').attr('data-key', pageKey);
            if (pendingCount <= 6) {
                $('.img-gallery-main-btn').hide();
            }
        }
        else {
            $('.img-gallery-main-btn').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

The problem with the plugin is that there is not a 'refresh' method so though I am able to load the content in the DOM,it does not reflect in the carousel.

Please help.

Comment: Could you share jsfiddle link?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should `dispose` and after `initialize` slick with your `selector` when your ajax done.

```
$('WhateverYourSelector').slickLightbox({
    itemSelector: 'ExampleIdOrClassOrNameOrBlaBla'
  });
```

Or

```
$('WhateverYourSelector').slick();
```

Comment: I am only using slick-light box currently not slick carousel.So this helps me in creating a overlay on my image gallery.And destroying the slick-lightbox instance is not an option because that will completely close it.I need something which will load the images in the slick-lightbox dynamically WITHOUT closing it once the AJAX call is done.

Comment: both was just an example , I didnt use slick before. I  just open documentation and try to explain what I see :) .

Comment: Yeah.But I would be glad if you can tell me an approach to resolve the issue :)

Comment: I already said it , I think when page load you are loading slick, and slick create an `object` as `array` or `json` or somethink like that for make it light-box. And your other datas which you are loading with ajax are not in this `object`. So this will not work. You need to push this datas to slick for work well. 
Did  you never use [bootstrap-select ?](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/)

Comment: Also I cant see anything in your code about slick . better to send us your all code about what you are trying to do